# JSF 2 and file download with command button - problems with final redirect?

Tags: jsf, download, firebug

I want to have a possibility to download .txt file in my JSF application. I use h:command button this way:

```
<h:commandButton value="Download" actionListener="#{exportBean.downloadFile}">
<f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{upload.name}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I use this methods in backing bean: http://pastebin.com/BMAQSgTJ (that implementation is probably ok because server returns me that file I want to download - it is possible to see in firebug output, i paste it only if you were interested)

My problem is that when I "click" on h:commandButton to download file, there is no dialog window to save or open file... does anybody know where is the problem?

This is my firebug output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21435926/firebug.png

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace the AJAX `actionListener` in

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete file" actionListener="#{exportBean.deleteFile}">
```

to an `action`:

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete file" action="#{exportBean.deleteFile}">
```

Comment: What scope is your managed bean? And have you tried not using java NIO (just to cross check) and also closing your inputstream/outputstream (src, dest)

Comment: Scope is @CustomScoped(value = "#{window}") ...it is special type from IceFaces.